# Which Apps on my Mac need security updates?

Tags: security

I have a lot of software installed from sources other than the Apple Store. Is there a service to check which app have security updates ready to be downloaded? Opening each one on Fridays for a routine check sounds inefficient. For MacPorts, there is a script but I have stuff that comes from other sources too. Is this an unreasonable expectation to have? It seems technically feasible just to maintain a DB and query it with a list of package/version, package/version... getting back a list of update/version/url, update/version/url...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit: Better Option***

I found [AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/mac), which seems to do exactly what you're looking for, using a bunch of different sources, including Apple Update, Sparkle (which a lot of 3rd party apps use to push updates), Microsoft Updates and more. It also has the option of installing the updates right from the app.

---

*Original Answer*

MacUpdate offers [RSS feeds](http://www.macupdate.com/rssfeeds/) of updates to all the software it tracks. You could use that, with something to filter for items matching software you have installed ([Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)) might be useful for that) to give you a list of updates to any of your apps.

It's probably not a comprehensive solution depending on the obscurity of some of your apps, but it's probably the closest you'll get to a single source.

The other alternative might be creating a script that periodically checks provided URLs for all your software for any changes, then notifies you in some way.

Comment: Building on this, I would also like to note that if an app is not running, it isn't really a security vulnerability.  And since most apps will regularly check for updates (if they are running), this is an issue which probably shouldn't give you that much concern.  That being said, the methods detailed here are both great solutions for making sure that everything is up-to-date.